# Javascript not waiting for onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to execute this code but for some reason that I cannot figure out the RoundRobin function will execute onload rather than onclick. I have tried removing window.onload or replacing it with document.onload. All I want is for this line `document.getElementById("tableButton").onclick  = RoundRobin(teamsIn);` to wait for the onclick trigger.

```
var selectedTeams = [];

window.onload = function() {
// JavaScript Document



// add selected teams to array

var teamList = document.getElementById("teamDropdown");
teamList.onchange = function addTeams() {


    if (selectedTeams.length > 7) {

        alert("no more teams")

    } else {
        var county = document.getElementById("teamDropdown").value;
        selectedTeams.push(county);
    }

    alert("counties selected are: " + selectedTeams);
}



var teamsIn = 0;
teamsIn = selectedTeams.length;

document.getElementById("tableButton").onclick = RoundRobin(teamsIn);

// slideshow.
var imageArray = new Array();
imageArray[0] = new Image()
imageArray[0].src = "Sponsors/aib.png"

imageArray[1] = new Image()
imageArray[1].src = "Sponsors/centra.jpg"

imageArray[2] = new Image()
imageArray[2].src = "Sponsors/eircom.png"

imageArray[3] = new Image()
imageArray[3].src = "Sponsors/etihad.png"

imageArray[4] = new Image()
imageArray[4].src = "Sponsors/liberty.jpg"

imageArray[5] = new Image()
imageArray[5].src = "Sponsors/supervalu.png"


var step = 0;

function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('slideshow').src = imageArray[step].src
    if (step < 5)
        step++
        else
            step = 0
    setTimeout("slideShow()", 4000)
}



function RoundRobin(teams) {

    alert(teams);
    var i;
    var ret = "";
    var round;
    var numplayers = 0;
    numplayers = parseInt(teams) + parseInt(teams % 2);
    numplayers = parseInt(numplayers);
    alert(numplayers);
    var a = new Array(numplayers - 1);
    var alength = a.length;
    for (var x = 0; x < (numplayers); x++) {
        a[x] = "Team " + (x + 1);
    }
    if (numplayers != parseInt(teams)) {
        a[alength] = "BYE";
    }
    var pos;
    var pos2;
    ret = "----- ROUND #1-----<br />"
    for (var r1a = 0; r1a < (numplayers / 2); r1a++) {
        ret += a[r1a] + " vs. " + a[alength - r1a] + "<br />"
    }
    for (round = 2; round < alength + 1; round++) {
        ret += "<br /><br />----- ROUND #" + round + "-----<br />"
        ret += a[0] + " vs. " + a[alength - (round - 1)] + "<br />"

        for (i = 2; i < (numplayers / 2) + 1; i++) {
            pos = (i + (round - 2))
            if (pos >= alength) {
                pos = ((alength - pos)) * -1
            } else {
                pos = (i + (round - 2))
            }

            pos2 = (pos - (round - 2)) - round
            if (pos2 > 0) {
                pos2 = (alength - pos2) * -1
            }

            if (pos2 < (alength * -1)) {
                pos2 += alength
            }
            ret += a[(alength + pos2)]
            ret += " vs. " + a[(alength - pos)] + "<br />"
        }
    }
    var text = document.getElementById('fixtures');
    text.innerHTML = ret;
    return ret
}

// round robin format

}
```

Comment: You are executing `RoundRobin` function, `RoundRobin(teamsIn)`, and assigning it to `onclick`.

Comment: any console errors??

Answer (score 6):

What's happening is that you call the function, then you assing the return value to the `onclick` property. For the event handler to work you need to assign a function to the property.

Wrap the call in a function expression:

```
document.getElementById("tableButton").onclick = function(){
  RoundRobin(teamsIn);
};
```

Comment: Thanks but the function is still not working the way it should. The array.length is not working. Im not sure why but the alerts still say 0 even though they should have 8 teams. I know its not your problem, I'll figure it out.

Comment: @nedduff: You set `teamsIn = selectedTeams.length;` at the beginning, but you don't update the variable when `selectedTeams` changes. Perhaps you want to use `selectedTeams.length` in the call to `RoundRobin`.